# Python & JSON - Запись значений в переменную

Tags: python, json

Я не знаю как правильно описать заголовок, если кто то может, отредактируйте.

Я работаю с vk_api, при вызове метода users.get он возвращает информацию в JSON формате. То есть вот так:

```
[{'id': 2281337, 'first_name': 'name', 'last_name': 'lastname', 'is_closed': False, 'can_access_closed': True}]
```

После ответа, мне нужно поместить допустим значение объекта id в переменную userid. Как это сделать?

1) Как оказалось, это не JSON

2) Если у кого такая же проблема, ответ andreymal помог: `userid = ответ[0]['id']`

Comment: `userid = ответ[0]['id']`

Comment: Это не JSON формат.

Comment: @КириллМалышев ну а какой тогда?

Comment: Это python-объекты, см. комментарий @andreymal

Comment: @КириллМалышев спасибо, буду знать

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо, все получилось <3

Comment: @FruthyzGang, удалите ответ из вопроса и напишите ответ в поле для ответа.

Comment: ВК отправляет именно `JSON`, но `vk_api` заботливо парсит его для Вас (просто к сведению).